# How To Assign A Number To A Line From An Array Using PHP

Tags: php

Here is the script as I am using it now:

```
<?php 
echo '<html><body>';

// Data from a flat file  
$dataArray = file('text.dat');

// Get the current page  
if (isset($_REQUEST['page'])) {
    $currentPage = $_REQUEST['page'];
} else {
    $currentPage = 'some default value';
}

// Pagination settings  
$perPage = 3;  
$numPages = ceil(count($dataArray) / $perPage);  
if(!$currentPage || $currentPage > $numPages)  
    $currentPage = 0;  
$start = $currentPage * $perPage;  
$end = ($currentPage * $perPage) + $perPage;

// Extract ones we need  
foreach($dataArray AS $key => $val)  
{  
    if($key >= $start && $key < $end)  
        $pagedData[] = $dataArray[$key];  
}

foreach($pagedData AS $item) {  
    $item = explode('||', $item);
    echo '<a href="/'. $item[1] .'/index.php">'. $item[0] .'</a><br>';
}

if($currentPage > 0 && $currentPage < $numPages)  
    echo '<a href="?page=' . ($currentPage - 1) . '">« Previous page</a><br>';  
if($numPages > $currentPage && ($currentPage + 1) < $numPages)  
    echo '<a href="?page=' . ($currentPage + 1) . '" class="right">Next page »</a><br>';

echo '</body></html>';
?>
```

And here is the contents of text.dat

```
Fun||http://site.com/page11.html
Games||http://site.com/page12.html
Toys||http://site.com/page13.html
Sports||http://site.com/page16.html
Fishing||http://site.com/page18.html
Pools||http://site.com/page41.html
Boats||http://site.com/page91.html
```

Here is my question. There are Seven lines in this array. How can I display the line number (I think it is $key) next to my displayed link? I should end up a list of links, each with it own number like:

```
LINE NUMBER - <a href="/'. $item[1] .'/index.php">'. $item[0] .'</a><br />
```

Thanks for any assistance.....

Comment: gave u heard about magic constant [__LINE__](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the line number from the file and not the line number of the output.  If so, then change this:

```
// Extract ones we need  
foreach($dataArray AS $key => $val)  
{  
    if($key >= $start && $key < $end)  
        $pagedData[] = $dataArray[$key];  
}

foreach($pagedData AS $item) {  
    $item = explode('||', $item);
    echo '<a href="/'. $item[1] .'/index.php">'. $item[0] .'</a><br>';
}
```

to something like this:

```
// Extract ones we need  
foreach($dataArray AS $key => $val)  
{  
    if($key >= $start && $key < $end)  
        $pagedData[$key] = $dataArray[$key];  
}

foreach($pagedData AS $key => $item) {  
    $item = explode('||', $item);
    echo $key+1 . ' - <a href="/'. $item[1] .'/index.php">'. $item[0] .'</a><br>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need a counter variable, like `$i`, that is incremented in the loop.

```
$i = $start;
foreach ($pagedData as $item) {
    $item = explode('||', $item);
    echo $i. ' - <a href ...';
    $i++;
}
```

**Edit**: Started `$i` at `$start` so it matches the numbering of `$key`.

Comment: I didn't know you could increment $i when putting it in an echo, but I guess it's the same as echo theReuturnValOfSomeFunction();

Comment: @Renesis that's not because you can do it that you should :p I find this less clear and easy to read.